# Dart missing dart.js

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-eclipse-plugin

Iam using Eclipse 4.4 and Dart plugin 1.7.2
I added a Dart project to my workspace. Rightclick on the .html run as --> Browser launch

i get in my Console:

```
--- 08:58:14 Starting pub serve : fff ---
[web] GET /fff.html => fff|web/fff.html
[web] GET /packages/browser/dart.js => Could not find asset browser|lib/dart.js.
[web] GET /fff.css => fff|web/fff.css
```

****EDIT****

this is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: fff
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  browser: any
```

and i already build and update, but now i saw a error: Missing Dart SDK.
But i already installed it via the dart plugin and now plugin says that i installed sdk. but in my error console i got the missing dart sdk. i need to create a reference?

Hans

Comment: I assume you called `pub get` or `pub upgrade` first? You can try running `pub build` form the directory containing `pubspec.yaml` and then opening the page from Chrome `http://localhost:8080` and post additional error output if you get some. Can you also please add your `pubspec.yaml` file to your question.

Comment: Adding the `dart-sdk/bin` to the path might help.

Comment: i had already done this before. BUT... I added dart sdk to my path and in my eclipse the dartplugin added a dart-sdk folder too. This folder only contains a dart.exe . the folder i added to my path contains no dart.exe but a /bin, /include and /lib folder

Comment: i copied the dark-sdk folder from my path to my eclipse dart sdk folder... now its working.  Thanks Günter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied my dart-sdk Folder which i downloaded [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/download.html) in my eclipse folder... then it worked. but i added the dart-sdk/bin to my windows-path too.